# How to replace content using a bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script to achieve the output of replacing the content in abc.txt file

```
#! /bin/bash/

echo "Please write the file name"

read file

old = "abc"

new = "bcd"

sed -i "s/$old/$new/g" $file
```

output: I am not getting the result. Please let me know where I did mistakes?

Comment: `#! /bin/bash/` ?

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out several problems with this script. I recommend running your scripts through it and fixing what it points out, at least until you get more experienced at shell scripting.